# Types commented out in Swift Objective-C header?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using a Swift class in Objective-C, but in the automatically generated `<productname>-Swift.h` header some of the types are commented out:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) /* [String : [ProgressCallback]] */ progressListeners;
@property (nonatomic, copy) /* [String : [CompleteCallback]] */ completeListeners;
@property (nonatomic, copy) /* [String : [ErrorCallback]] */ errorListeners;
```

I know these typed dictionaries of arrays cannot be preserved in Objective-C, but why not comment out the whole property or just call it a NSDictionary?  As it is, it causes syntax errors.  I don't need these properties in Objective-C, is there anything I can do to make it generate a valid header file?

Comment: [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I'm guessing that it's intentional.  By commenting out just the typing it gives you an error message and forces you to fix the problem.  And no, I'm not sure what the problem is other than insure that the Arrays are Arrays of Objective-C compatible objects.

Answer (score 1):

I got past this by making the Swift members private.  It looks like private members are excluded from the Swift header.

So, to be concrete, in this case you might define your members like this in Swift:

```
@objc class MyClass {
  private var progressListeners : [String : [ProgressCallBack]] = [:]
  private var completeListeners : [String : [CompleteCallBack]] = [:]
  private var errorListeners : [String : [ErrorCallBack]] = [:]
}
```